# NSXMLParserDelegate foundCharacters function returning empty

Tags: swift, nsxmlparser

I am new in Swift language and I am with a problem in parsing a XML. It seems to be readable because returns the object count, but it is not printing the values.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<carros>
    <carro>
        <nome>Ferrari FF</nome>
        <desc><![CDATA[A Ferrari FF acaba de ser revelada. Se trata do primeiro modelo da marca a ter tração integral. Além disso, ele conta com um motor dianteiro V12. Se trata de um modelo GT de quatro lugares que não só substitui a 612 mas também atrai um novo tipo de cliente, daquele que gosta de percorrer caminhos mais difíceis que exigem tração integral. Este modelo revolucionário (dentro da marca) tem um novo chassi com entre-eixos maior, além de suspensão independente que incorpora a última geração de amortecedores ajustáveis, além de freios de cerâmica da Brembo.
     ]]>
        </desc>
        <url_info>
            http://www.ferrari.com/English/GT_Sport%20Cars/CurrentRange/FF/Pages/FF.aspx
        </url_info>
        <url_foto>
            http://www.livroandroid.com.br/livro/carros/esportivos/Ferrari_FF.png
        </url_foto>
        <url_video>
            http://www.livroiphone.com.br/carros/esportivos/ferrari_ff.mp4
        </url_video>
        <latitude>44.532218</latitude>
        <longitude>10.864019</longitude>
    </carro>
    <carro>
        <nome>AUDI GT Spyder</nome>
        <desc><![CDATA[O mais novo modelo limitado a 333 unidades que vem para preencher a lacuna de modelo top de linha, vaga desde que o cupê do mesmo modelo, há um ano atrás, esgotou todos os pedidos ainda ano passado.
O segredo do baixo peso é fazer uso de fibra de carbono para boa parte dos painéis de carroceria, e fibra de vidro para os bancos concha. Além disso, o teto da capota é tecido e se retrai em 19 segundos, podendo-se recolhe-lo andando em velocidades de até 50km/h.
     ]]>
        </desc>
        <url_info>
            http://www.audi.com.br/br/brand/pt.html
        </url_info>
        <url_foto>
            http://www.livroandroid.com.br/livro/carros/esportivos/Audi_Spyder.png
        </url_foto>
        <url_video>
            http://www.livroiphone.com.br/carros/esportivos/audi_gt.mp4
        </url_video>
        <latitude>-23.564224</latitude>
        <longitude>-46.653156</longitude>
    </carro>
</carros>
```

This is my `NSXMLParser` code, all the prints are okay, except the `tempString` print. I am not sure but I think that something is going wrong on the `foundCharacters` function.

```
import Foundation

class XMLCarroParser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var carros: Array<Carro> = []
    //variaveis auxiliares para o parser
    var tempString: String = ""
    var carro: Carro?

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        if(elementName == "carro") {
            //Tag <carro> encontrada, cria um novo objeto carro
            carro = Carro()
            println("creating an object carro")
        }

    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser?!, foundCharacters string: String!) {
        // Novos caracteres foram encontrados no XML entao cria a string e faz trim
        tempString += string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

        if("carros" == elementName) {
            //Tag de fim </carros> encontrada. Significa que terminou o xml
            println("destroing the object carro")
            return
        }

        if("carro" == elementName) {
            //Insere carro no array e limpa o objeto
            self.carros.append(carro!)
            carro = nil
            println("destroing the object carro");

            return
        }

        /*
         Se nao é a tag <carro>, pode ser as tags <nome>, <desc>, etc.
         Copia os valores do XML para o objeto carro
         Se eistirem tags com o mesmo nome da @property do Carro, o valor sera copiado.
         */
        if(carro != nil) {
            if("nome" == elementName) {
                carro!.nome = "nome";
                print("  nome ")
                println(tempString)
            } else if("desc" == elementName) {
                carro!.desc = tempString;
                println("  desc")
            } else if("url_foto" == elementName) {
                carro!.url_foto = tempString
                println("  foto")
            } else if("url_info" == elementName) {
                println("  info")
                carro!.url_info = tempString
            } else if("url_video" == elementName) {
                println("  video")
                carro!.url_video = tempString
            } else if("latitude" == elementName) {
                println("  latitude")
                carro!.latitude = tempString
            } else if("longitude" == tempString) {
                println("  longitude")
                carro!.longitude = tempString
            }

            tempString = ""
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
        NSLog("failure error: %@", parseError)
    }


}
```

Comment: Note, in addition to the issues I note below, if you keep your current `didEndElement`, note that you have a couple of issues there (e.g. if `elementName` is `nomo`, you're saving `"nomo"` rather than `tempString`; your test for `"longitude" == tempString` should be `"longitude" == elementName`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the signature of that method is incorrect. It is likely not getting called at all. It should be:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
    tempString += string!
}
```

Note, I have removed `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` from `foundCharacters`. You do not want to do that there, because it's possible that it will take multiple calls to `foundCharacters` to return a single string value, and the net effect of trimming in this routine is that you could trim out spaces not only at the start and end of the string, but also in the middle of the string. (For example, if the element value was "this is a test" and was returned in two calls to `foundCharacters`, once with "this is " and again with "a test", if you have `foundCharacter` trim characters, it will incorrectly represent it as "this isa test".)

Instead, do that in `didEndElement`, where you save the string.

---

By the way, if `Carro` was key-value coding compliant (easily accomplished if it is an `NSObject` subclass), the parser code is simplified:

```
class XMLCarroParser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var carros = [Carro]()
    var tempString: String?
    var carro: Carro?
    let fields = ["nome", "desc", "url_foto", "url_info", "url_video", "longitude", "latitude"]

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        if elementName == "carro" {
            carro = Carro()
        } else if contains(fields, elementName) {
            tempString = ""
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
        tempString? += string ?? ""
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "carro" {
            self.carros.append(carro!)
            carro = nil
        } else if contains(fields, elementName) {
            carro?.setValue(tempString!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()), forKey: elementName)
            tempString = nil
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
        NSLog("failure error: %@", parseError)
    }

}
```

Comment: It worked partially...when I use carro?.setValue(tempString!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()), forKey: elementName) it says that carro doesn't have the setValue method..so I decided to use all ifs just to test...and it worked...is there something wrong using carro?.setValue?

Comment: @EricLongo `Carro` has to be key-value coding compliant for that to work. The easiest way to achieve that is to make `Carro` an `NSObject` subclass. Clearly, if you don't want to use `setValue:forKey:`, then leave your `didEndElement` as is (though obviously moving the trimming of the `tempString` there and fixing the `nomo` and `longitude` bugs I noted in my comment to your original question).

Comment: Thats it... I made Carro an NSObject subclass...it is perfect now..Thanks a lot.